# Fetch Specific Data from SQLite Webservice Database by column name in Android

Tags: android, database, web-services, sqlite

I have code which is fetch data from whole database by using this query.

```
public Cursor getQuestion()
{
    return databasesql.query(TABLE_QUESTIONS, new String[]{COLUMN_QUESTIONS}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Now I want to fetch data by matching specific column name from database. So which query should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
public Cursor getQuestion()
{
    return databasesql.query(TABLE_QUESTIONS, new String[]{COLUMN_QUESTIONS}, COLUMN_NAME + "='SOMETHING'", null, null, null, null); 

}
```

You can have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29): The *selection* parameter is what you need.

Comment: I tried this query by replacing my column name but still it gives the same result. Here is the code which I tried as below:                          public Cursor getQuestion()
 {  return databasesql.query(TABLE_QUESTIONS, new String[]{COLUMN_QUESTIONS}, COLUMN_CHAPTERS + "='Universe'", null, null, null, null); }